# Could i use datasets from different sources when doing deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, distribution

Let's say it simply, i want to detect whether a patient has lung cancer or not utilizing chest X-rays images.

The problem i faced here were:
I have 3 datasets from 3 different sources, 3 of theme were all chest X-rays images, assuming all other medical properties are same too. 
The first dataset contains of 130 images of normal and cancer-diagnosed patient.
The second dataset contains of 40 images of normal patients
The third dataset contains of 120 images of cancerous patients.

Thus, i want to combine 3 datasets from 3 different sources to train and evaluate my model.
I intend to mix and shuffle all data then beginning splitting into train,validation,test set. Is that okay?

Is there anymore thing / characteristic that i should pay attention to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, normally mixing the datasets is not a good thing, especially when datasets are not very similar to each other. However, in your case, you say all of them are X-ray images of human lung. We expect all the images to be very similar, so mixing them would not affect the performance in a bad way, but in a good way I guess.

Having a lot of data is always good in deep learning field. Especially big neural networks need huge amounts of data. Your data seems less to me. I recommend you to use simple networks.

In short, is it likely that all the images combined came from the same source? i.e they resemble each other in general, but only differ in parts where there is infection? If so, go ahead.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your comment, in general they differ in shaped and regions of lesion. But in normal case, it is same. However, i have another question, what does it mean "the distribution" in my dataset, is it the ratio of normal and cancer class?

Comment: @TotallyNew Can you give the whole sentence and context? But, yes, for example, I guess homogen distribution means you have similar number of classes.

Comment: I just wonder, for a dataset that contains only images of normal and cancerous patient, what is the distribution of the dataset. Does the distribution mean the ratio between cancerous and normal class

Comment: @TotallyNew Yes. It means how much of the images are cancerous image, and how much of them are normal image.